# Adding GET parameters to a CMS page results in 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a CMS page with the URL key of `"foobar"` (so `www.domain.com/foobar`) and it works fine.

As soon as I add a `?value=123` on the end I see a 404 error. I have other CMS pages that work fine to take parameters using GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with my parameter being `"store"` I guess it's a reserved word in 1.9, in Magento 1.4.1 it was available.

Comment: Please select this as the answer to your question so this drops off unanswered questions, thanks!

Comment: Yeah I have to wait 2 days though.